# How to keep UITextField text when the view changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I've got two `UITextFields`, the input of which I store into strings `player1` and `player2`. These `UITextFields` are on a `ViewController` called by a popOver segue. How can I make the `UITextFields` keep displaying their text once the view has changed?

I tried `textFieldOne.text = player1;` in the `viewDidLoad` section of the `ViewController` to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post any code? Especially, how do you create those text fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loaded view's delegate isn't `ViewController`, your code wouldn't be executed. So be sure that your code is on the delegate of the loaded view. Use also `[textFieldOne setText:player1]`. It's always better to call the setter method instead of setting the ivar directly. Then be sure that your `UITextField` is not nil and correctly binded. Use `textFieldOne = [[UITextField alloc] init]` to initialise it. If your problem continues, try also `[textFieldOne setText:self.player1]`. Hope it helps..

EDIT : 
Got the solution here. You should use `NSUserDefaults` so your player names are stored and can be used in each view and even after re-opening your app (if you don't want this you can erase the defaults at lunch. Here is your bunch of code you need to change :

hardOne.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[hard1ON setOn:switchState animated:NO];
//read player names to user defaults
[textFieldOne setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"player1"]]; 
[textFieldTwo setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"player2"]];
}

- (IBAction) returnKey1
{
player1 = [textFieldOne text];
[players addObject:(player1)];
//set player1's name to user defaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[textFieldOne text] forKey:@"player1"];
}

- (IBAction) returnKey2
{
player2 = [textFieldTwo text];
[players addObject:(player2)];
NSLog(@"array: %@",players);
//set player2's name to user defaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[textFieldTwo text] forKey:@"player2"];
}
```

Comment: If I use that `textFieldOne = [[UITextField alloc] init]` line of code, I get an exception error when I try to put text into `textFieldOne`. It still doesn't work though. I'm not sure if it's anything to do with the logic in that viewDidLoad sets the two textFields to player1 and player2 before they have anything stored in them.. Then I enter data in, and I'm not sure if those variables are saved when I reopen the ViewController. Hmm, confusing.

Comment: Go to [Gists](https://gist.github.com) to upload your full code. It's difficult to tell from here. Or better, e-mail me your project to moraybaruh@me.com

Comment: Edited my answer with the solution!